# Is it ok to stack multiple CustomPainter in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, stack, flutter-custompainter

Is it ok to stack multiple CustomPainter in a Stack widget?

For example:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    RepaintBoundary(
        child: CustomPaint(
      size: Size(imgSource.width.toDouble(), imgSource.height.toDouble()),
      painter: BackgroundImagePainter(imgSource),
    )),
    RepaintBoundary(
        child: CustomPaint(
      isComplex: true,
      willChange: true,
      size: Size(imgSource.width.toDouble(), imgSource.height.toDouble()),
      painter: GpsMarkerPainter(lMarkerDisplay, scale: _currentScale),
    )),
  ],
),
```

In this example i use one painter (BackgroundImagePainter) to draw the background image one time and another CustomPainter (GpsMarkerPainter) to draw updated marker positions.

What is the best practice if i would like to display a compass that redraws every second. Can i just add a CustomPainter for that as well or would it be better to put them together in one CustomPainter even they would have different triggers for redraw?

Answer (score 2):

It is completely OK to stack `CustomPaint` widgets.

The same way you organise custom `Stateless` or `Stateful` widgets, you can organize your `CustomPaint` the way you want and split them the way you want. Usually, you split them by feature so they aren't 500 lines each.